# I can't display Classwizard anymore in MFC project in VS 2019

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2019, classwizard

My project started out years ago. Now using VS 2019.

Whilst I can right-click and add event handlers (since it uses a new VS wizard), and I can right-click the class and add generic variables (since it uses a new VS wizard) I can't display class wizard any more:

[image: Classwizard 1]

I have tried cleaning the project and tried renaming my folder.

It refuses to display and shows that message:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

The other error message that shows is:

[image: Classwizard 2]

> The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070075 (E_INVALIDARG))

This means it is very hard for me to attach new variables to new controls on dialog resources.

I have researched this issue and can't find a solution that works for my 2019 MFC project.

## Update

I tried using the **Visual Studio Installer** and **Repair** and that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I recently moved to vs2019 so I checked. I do get an event handler dialog, But it does not find my dialog class, I have to pick it from a list off all my classes! I'm version 4.7.03062. I have been taking the updates, got one about a week ago.

Comment: @lakeweb Yes, some of my dialog resources work with the new wizard. And I too had to select the class from the list in some instances. But these particular dialogs refuse to work.

Comment: I have presented [the problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/615863/mfc-add-dialog-variable-add-event-handler-problem.html). I've included your post here. So, is your project really large and/or you are using multi-byte?

Comment: @lakeweb No way! I did the same! See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/613831/cant-add-a-new-variable-to-a-control-on-mfc-dialog.html

Comment: Uno, I searched, especially the latest messages, It did not come up! Well, maybe they will fix it sooner :) I would rather not create the next dialog var/event stuff by hand.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have a heads up on this. I created fresh solution for my project for other reasons, like moving to unicode. (what a job that was!). The problem went away. There is something in the older .vcxproj file that caused the problem.

Comment: @lakeweb Thanks. For now I am avoiding having to do all that. But thanks for the advice. If it comes to do I will do it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I did try to edit the old .vcxproj but could not resolve the issue. It is probably just a few lines, but which ones? At the least, I'm very sure the fix is there now.